# Celery не работает с брокером выдает эту ошибку, кто сталкировался с подобным можете помочь?

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery

```
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)


@celery.task
def find_fibonacci_async(number):
    def fib(n):
        if n == 1:
            return 0
        if n == 2:
            return 1

        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

    result = fib(number)
    return result


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

```
kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Табуляции для начала исправьте

Comment: табуляция сохранена верно

Comment: `def make_celery` и `celery = ...` не могут быть с одинаковым отступом.

Comment: так я ща поменяю пример, посмотрите

Comment: и он до сих пор пишет ошибку соединения

Comment: redis точно запущен и слушает на localhost:6379?

Comment: Да. я ввел команду  redis-cli ping

Comment: и он ответил, PONG